# How can I style angular UI pagination

Tags: javascript, css, pagination, frontend, angular-ui

I am using [Angular UI 2.5.0](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) for my pagination. I was wondering if there is any way to style the pagination bar to something like the image below.

Default:

[image: Default pagination bar]

Custom (which I want):

[image]

I do not need any kinds of css classes as I already have them. I do no know how to apply them to the paginaton bar. Of course I will add previous and next button.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this property. more details in documentation.

> template-url (Default: uib/template/pagination/pagination.html) - Override the template for the component with a custom provided template